# Getting updated Value from React Context

Tags: reactjs, react-context

I have an app which uses a global Time Value. All components need to use the same time value.
I have put this time value, named system_time, in context and want all components to be able to get the latest system_time from context.
How can I ensure that the context.system_time is updated every second and the updated system_time is available to all components whenever required?

Comment: you can use redux store or localStorage

Comment: I want to avoid Redux as I am using Context to hold data needed across components. I am presently using localstorage but am worried if accessing it multiple times a second has any performance issues.

Answer (score 0):

Use a mixture of `useState` and `useEffect`. Update state with `setInterval`, which you will set to 1000 milliseconds.  Then, just make sure you clear the interval when you unmount.

You might use something similar to this:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'

const App = () => {
  const [date, setDate] = useState()


  useEffect(() => {
    let interval = setInterval(() => setDate(Date.now()), 1000);
    
   //clear on unmount    
    return () => {
      clearInterval(interval)
    }
  })

  return (
    <div>
      {date}
    </div>
  )
}

export default App
```

Your return will look different, of course. But I just used that to demonstrate that it updates every second.

Then, just pass your state to your components.